# Tortoise HG "Out of Memory" While Trying to Clone Repo

Tags: clone, mercurial, repository, tortoise-hg

While trying to clone a ~500 MB repository onto my local drive using mercurial, I repeatedly get the "Out of Memory" error.  I have 2 GB of memory and I have never seen this.  I installed the latest version of mercurial, and I have tried using different authentications.  Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running into this issue myself, even on a 64-bit machine with 4 GB of RAM. It turns out to be a known issue in Mercurial on Windows:

http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1842

Essentially large files in the repository are causing memory fragmentation which prevents memory allocations from succeeding on Windows. Unfortunately the issue is not yet fixed and the last discussion on the ticket is from December of last year. It seems like the options at this point are:

- Run a 64 bit version of mercurial. ATM, I don't see any available for easy download on Windows, this may need to be built
- Somehow pare down the repo to remove the large files only, if possible.

Comment: Good answer...  Out of votes until later, but will return with +1 for you.